# AWS Codebuild - proceed to build only if commit message includes a string

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, continuous-integration, aws-codebuild

I'm trying to do something like CircleCI's [ci skip] tag, which lets developers "opt in" to building the project, i.e. the commit message determines whether a build proceeds. A `buildit` string in commit message would make the build proceed, otherwise it terminates in pre-build stage.

I'm aware of this project: https://github.com/thii/aws-codebuild-extras. It provides the git message as an environment variable, but not sure how to add an `if statement` in the buildspec.yml which would terminate the build early if `buildit` is absent from the message.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AWS CodeBuild - How to skip a build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48893479/aws-codebuild-how-to-skip-a-build)

Answer (score 1):

To at least have an IF statement in the buildspec file.

```yaml
version: 0.2
phases:
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo Installing source NPM dependencies...
      - npm install
      - |
        if [ "$TEST_ONLY" -ne "TRUE" ] ; then 
          echo "NEED TO SET $ENV"
          exit 1
        fi
```